# Matrix norm induced from vector explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Can someone explain as thoroughly as possible what a matrix induced norm is? A concrete example would for this norm would help a lot...

$A \in C^{n \times n}, v \in C^n$

$|| A || = \displaystyle\sup_{v \neq 0}\frac{||Av||}{||v||}$

Thank you.

Comment: @bytei918 Please explain your question better.

Comment: The norm is defined as above. I don't understand what ||Av|| means and what the final result will be. An example for a chosen matrix would make things more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: $Av$ is another vector when $v$ is a vector. Assuming one puts the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{C}^{n},$ the norm of a vector $u \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ is given by $\| u \| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} |u_{i}|^{2}}$, where the $u_{i}$ are the entries of $u$ (though other norms are possible). Armed with this information, to calculate the norm of a matrix is a matter of following the definitions. The sup is the least upper bound. It may help to note 
that the ratio $\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}$ is unchanged if we multiply $v$ by a non-zero scalar, so it suffices to consider vectors with $\| v \| = 1.$

Comment: Thank you. Everything is nice and clear now.

Answer (score 5):

One can view the induced norm as the largest factor by which $A$ can stretch any vector (while also changing its direction).

In other words, if we denote $\varphi := \|A\|$, then $\|Av\| \le \varphi \|v\|$, for all $v$, and $\varphi$ is the smallest nonnegative real number with such a property.

Note that the "stretch" above means "make longer by a factor (shorter if that factor is less than 1)" and "length" is dependent of the choice of the vector norm.

This, of course, is not a formal definition, but  more of a layman explanation if you have a hard time of grasping the concept.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you!